# Android app get's removed when I launch a different one on phone via Android Studio

Tags: android

Basically, I have 2 apps I'm working on in parallel, A and B. Till now, they both are shown on my phone (after launching them via Studio). Suddenly, when I launch App A, it seemed to have removed/uninstalled App B from the Phone and vice versa.  All I did was some SQL DB debugging via 'adb' and a lame attempt towards rooting my phone with Kingoroot (which failed and apparently added malware to my PC, but I doubt if it's related).

So what could have caused an App being removed when I launch a different one?

Comment: Both's package name are same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your application id in build.gradle file. The application id has to be unique so it doesn't get replaced by another one.

The application id config should looks similar to this

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "your uniuqe app id"
```

Android OS using this id to determine the app identity. Using different application id should solve your problem.

Comment: ha ! I was just zeroing in on that. I tried to search via 'Ctrl-shft-f' but it didn't show anything, only in 'created' files, but then I checked the gradle files and noticed my copy-n-paste snafu, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Please check that if you have same package name in both applications..

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever installed both apps in your phone at the same time?
If not, both apps may have the same package name.
It means both apps are the same with different versions.
So, at a time only one app is get installed.